# How to address the error has both : and :: entries while using gnu make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I am trying to port a new module into my project. The module has its own make file. I have no background or experience with the make build system, so I decided to use the following command:

```
make -f Makefile -f ../newmodule/tbt/makefile
```

But I get the following errors:

> ../newmodule/tbt/makefile:14: make/macros.mk: No such file or
>   directory
>       ../newmodule/tbt/makefile:66: *** target file `all' has both : and :: entries.  Stop.

Please correct me if I am wrong; it is my understanding that my first error is because I issued make from my main project, and I need to somehow configure it to look into the directory of `../newmodule/tbt/make` to find `macros.mk`. Would anyone be able to suggest an effective way of addressing this issue? What is the best way to include the contents of `../newmodule/tbt/make` folder?

My 2nd error seems to be exactly what make complains about, which is having : and :: in the two make files for the target `"all"`. I can not follow the 2nd make file very closely, but there is not much to the lines that have this target. I am thinking of changing it to `My_all`, and configure this new variable as the default target of the new module. I am not even sure if my terminology is correct. "all" is called the default target for make right? I have reviewed most of the make file document, but it is 5 am, and I do not recall some things.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this error during compilation of some package under OpenWrt. The problem was in the VERSION declaration in the Makefile.

So, check if you have declared anything with unnecessary spaces or comments after some variable.

Removing the comment or space after variables should work.

Answer (score -1):

Try running two separate `make -f myMakefile` commands, one from each module directory so that the relative paths work out properly as you have already observed that you current directory when executing `make` may be part of the problem.